# When were self-locking doors invented and when did they become commonplace?

Tags: engineering

In the 1950s in The Netherlands, it was common for people to hang a little rope through the mailbox, so that children (which apparently did not have a copy of the key) could let themselves in at any time.

On the outside, it looked like this:

[outside of door with rope through mailbox http://www.bottercourant.nl/images/nieuws/2016/12_December/SFA007002142.jpg](http://www.bottercourant.nl/images/nieuws/2016/12_December/SFA007002142.jpg)
*Source: [Botter Courant](http://www.bottercourant.nl/nieuws/algemeen/11379-touwtje-aan-de-brievenbus-tijdens-kerst-in-de-vesting)*

And on the inside:

[image: inside of the same]
*Source: [user bjorntm, thingyverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:738142)*

Clearly, this is actually a work-around for people who have a self-locking door but rather wouldn't.  I've visited areas where people don't normally lock their doors, and even where the cultural expectation for a visitor (stranger or not) is to simply enter and shout *Hello!*.  Not locking the door in the first place would seem a rather more convenient solution.

In the history of locks and door locks in particular, when were self-locking doors invented and when did they become commonplace?

Answer (score 1):

One inventor of a self-locking door was [Leonardo da Vinci](https://books.google.de/books?id=50eWBAAAQBAJ&pg=PR52&lpg=PR52&dq=%22selbstschlie%C3%9Fende%20T%C3%BCr%22%20erfindung&source=bl&ots=xJVPvchziP&sig=Zg3JtRmvwcddTSAiolXLWQKujjc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKwcGxl5XUAhXCfywKHaN1AqAQ6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q=%22selbstschlie%C3%9Fende%20T%C3%BCr%22%20erfindung&f=false) (1452-1519). But certainly there were earlier applications, in particular by trappers for many centuries.

The second part of the question is not precisely enough formulated. What percentage is "common place".